# Scrapy yield from a non call back method

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to **scrape** a html file that has a json object with all the required test case data , but processing of the json happens in "find" and "parseTestCaseDetails" method where iteratively i get the test case details , which i finally parse in "findInterestedFields" , so my requirement is to yield the details of test cases to a json file from the the last method called in the hierarchy i.e  findInterestedFields , is it possible to achieve this??

Thanks in advance!

```python
import scrapy
import datetime
import json
import re
import collections
import time
import os
import js2xml
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector


class AltiplanoAVInprogressTCSpiderTest(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "AltiplanoAVInprogressTCSpiderTest"
    buildNumber = []
    FormatedBuildTime = []
    keys = []
    testcaseName=''
    testcaseSuit=''
    testcaseDoc=''
    def start_requests(self):
        print os.environ["jenkinsdomain"]

        urls = [
            os.environ["jenkinsdomain"] + "/job/InprogressFlakyAndBlockedTestCaseDetails/lastSuccessfulBuild/"
        ]

        for url in urls:
            print url
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, errback=self.parseerror)

    def parseerror(self, failure):
        print failure

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        buildNumberString = hxs.select('normalize-space(//*[@id="main-panel"]/h1/text())').extract_first()
        self.buildNumber = buildNumberString.split("#")[-1].split("(")[0].strip()
        buildTimeUnformatd = buildNumberString.split("(")[-1].split(")")[0].strip().replace("PM", "").replace("AM", "")
        buildTimeUnformatd = buildTimeUnformatd.strip()
        t = time.strptime(buildTimeUnformatd, "%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S")
        self.FormatedBuildTime = time.strftime('%d %b %y %H:%M IST', t)
        static_testDetailsUrl = os.environ[
                                    "jenkinsdomain"] + "XX/Inprogress-ANV.html"
        yield scrapy.Request(url=static_testDetailsUrl, callback=self.parseTestDetails, errback=self.parseerror)


    def find(self, key, dictionary):
        for k, v in dictionary.iteritems():
            if k == key:
                yield v
                self.parseTestCaseDetails(v)
            elif isinstance(v, dict):
                for result in self.find(key, v):
                    yield result
            elif isinstance(v, list):
                for d in v:
                    for result in self.find(key, d):
                        yield result

    def parseTestCaseDetails(self, testcases):
        # get the list of test cases and again parse them one by one to get the name and other fields
    for testcase in testcases:
        self.findInterestedFields(testcase)

    def findInterestedFields(self, dictionary):
    jsonLoad = json.dumps(dictionary, indent=4)
    loaded_json = json.loads(jsonLoad)
    readabledatetime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d %b %y %H:%M IST")
    for k, v in loaded_json.iteritems():
        if k == "name":
            testcaseName = v
        if k == "fullName":
            testcaseSuit = v
        if k == "doc":
            testcaseDoc = v
    
    yield {"name":"avInprogresstestcases",'avInprogresstestcases':{
                                        'testcaseName':testcaseName

                                        }}

 
    def parseTestDetails(self, response):
        data = response.xpath('//script[4]/text()').extract_first().strip()
        jstree = js2xml.parse(data)
        testDetailsInJson = js2xml.jsonlike.getall(jstree)
        jsonLoad = json.dumps(testDetailsInJson[0], indent=4)
        loaded_json = json.loads(jsonLoad)
        list(self.find('tests', loaded_json))
```

Comment: Please check you code formatting above. Your code is quite unusual and hard to follow. Have you worked through the [scrapy tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html)?

Comment: First as the previous member said there is issue in code formatting. For instance the content of `def findInterestedFields(self, dictionary):` or `def findInterestedFields(self, dictionary):` isn't well indented at all. Second, can you give example(s) of what your are exactly looking for.

Comment: Please, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve